# having trouble with expandable yui table

Tags: datatable, yui

I tried adding a button on a random row which once clicked adds few random rows below the clicked row and when button is clicked 2nd time, it removes all those added rows.

http://jafl.github.io/yui-modules/treeble/pg_all.html

I tried my best with no success.

Could someone please show me some example on how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example is much closer to what you are trying to do:

http://jafl.github.io/yui-modules/datatable-row-expansion/

You might even be able to use this module directly.